# Add Dynamic Row Table Not Displaying The Right Row

Tags: javascript, html, row, addition

I'm trying to add dynamic row of table in my code. And when I click on the add button it displays the incorrect row. It suppose to display the checkbox, dropdown and input text row instead of the header row. Below are the javascript and html code together with the incorrect output. Do I have to change the javascript code? I've also tried looking for the answer inside the web but I found nothing. Please help me thanks.

Javascript code:

```
<script>
function addRow(tableID){

var table=document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount=table.rows.length;
var row=table.insertRow(rowCount);
var colCount=table.rows[0].cells.length;
   for(var i=0;i<colCount;i++){
       var newcell=row.insertCell(i);
       newcell.innerHTML=table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
       switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type){
        case"select-one":newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex=0;
        break;
        case"checkbox":newcell.childNodes[0].checked=false;
        break;
        case"text":newcell.childNodes[0].value="";
        break;}}}

function deleteRow(tableID){
try{
var table=document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount=table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++){
    var row=table.rows[i];
    var chkbox=row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null!=chkbox&&true==chkbox.checked){
        if(rowCount<=1){alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
        break;}

    table.deleteRow(i);
    rowCount--;
    i--;}}}
    catch(e){alert(e);}}
</script>
```

HTML Code :

```
<input type="button" value="Add More" onClick="addRow('dataTable')">
<input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')">

<table id="dataTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>✓</th>
    <th> Relationship </th>
    <th> Name </th>
    <th> Occupation </th>
    <th> Phone Number </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="fam_relationship[]" id="fam_relationship">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
        <option value="Spouse">Spouse</option>
        <option value="Father">Father</option>
        <option value="Mother">Mother</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fam_name[]" id="fam_name"> </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fam_occupation[]" id="fam_occupation"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fam_phone[]" id="fam_phone"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `0` into `1` at the following line:

```
newcell.innerHTML=table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
```

up here `rows[1]` instead `rows[0]`

```js
function addRow(tableID) {

  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
    switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
      case "select-one":
        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
        break;
      case "checkbox":
        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
        break;
      case "text":
        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
        break;
    }
  }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
      var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
      if (null != chkbox && true === chkbox.checked) {
        if (rowCount <= 1) {
          alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
          break;
        }

        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Add More" onClick="addRow('dataTable')">
<input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')">

<table id="dataTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>✓</th>
    <th>Relationship</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Occupation</th>
    <th>Phone Number</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk">
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="fam_relationship[]" id="fam_relationship">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
        <option value="Spouse">Spouse</option>
        <option value="Father">Father</option>
        <option value="Mother">Mother</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="fam_name[]" id="fam_name">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="fam_occupation[]" id="fam_occupation">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="fam_phone[]" id="fam_phone">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```